# How to change value of an object from a function in c++?

Tags: c++, function, class, initialization

### Scenario

I am in the process of learning C++, so please forgive my naivety. I have attempted to build my own class, objects and methods - each of which seem to work as expected. However I am running into issues with what seems to be *uninitialized storage* (and possibly the use of local objects?) however I would like to know how to fix it, if indeed it is meant to be, or an alternative. My current train of thought is that the object needs to be passed...however that could be way off...

### Code

```
//header
class Car{
public:
    USHORT GetMin();                            
    void SetMin(USHORT min);    
private:
    USHORT itsMinPrice;                                                                     
};

USHORT Car::GetMin(){
    return itsMinPrice;
}

void Car::SetMin(USHORT min){
    itsMinPrice = min;
}
```

-

```
void StartingPrices(){
    Car Mercedes;
    std::cout << Mercedes.GetMin() << "\n";
    Mercedes.SetMin(50);

    std::cout << Mercedes.GetMin()<< "\n";

}

int main(){
    float input;
    Car Mercedes;
    Mercedes.SetMin(100);
    StartingPrices();

    std::cout << Mercedes.GetMin() << "\n";

    std::cin >> input;
    return 0;
}
```

### Expected output

100, 50, 50

### Actual output

debug win32 - 52428, 50, 100

release win32 - 0, 50, 100

Comment: The object `Mercedes` inside `main()` is a distinct object from that inside `StartingPrices()`.

Comment: I assume that's because I identified it twice and haven't passed it as a parameter? Either way, is there a (simple) solution to reach my expected output?

Comment: if by "identified" you mean declared/defined, then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `StartingPrices` function, the `Mercedes` object you call `GetMin` is created on the line before, i.e., not the same object as the one you create in the `main` function.
That means that the object do not yet have `itsMinPrice` set to anything, hence the value will be garbage (that is, a value which you don't really have control over), in this case `52428` in debug and `0` in release.

What I think you wish to do is pass a reference of the `Mercedes` object from the `main` function into the `StartingPrices` function:

```
void StartingPrices(Car& mercedes){
   std::cout << Mercedes.GetMin() << "\n"; // Here the GetMin method will return 100.
   ...
}

int main(){
    ....
    Car Mercedes;
    Mercedes.SetMin(100);
    StartingPrices(Mercedes);
    ....
}
```

Its also a good idea to set the default value of the members in the `constructor` of the class.

Comment: Thank you for helping me overcome this stumbling block. This produces my expected output.

Comment: Glad I could help. Do you understand why it produces the expected output and why the old version did not? Read up on `references` and `function parameters` if you do not. :)

Comment: I do understand why each version produces their respective output, perhaps my question or research should have related to passing a reference as a parameter. Either way, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In your Car class you do not initialize your member variable `itsMinPrice` except when you call `SetMin`, this means there is a risk that you will use an uninitialized Car instance if you forget to call `SetMin` on it. Normally it is good to have initialization in a constructor of the class with some value e.g.

```
Car() : itsMinPrice(0) {
}
```

or create a constructor that takes an initial value

```
Car(USHORT minValue) : itsMinPrice(minValue) {
}
```

Comment: I'll be sure to adopt this best practice in future. Thanks for providing the code!